# Geth client: Transaction object has no from field

Tags: go-ethereum, json-rpc

I am using the ethClient to receive all transactions of a block.

```
    client, _ := ethclient.Dial(PROVIDER_URL)

    blockNumber := big.NewInt(15000000)
    block, err := client.BlockByNumber(context.Background(), blockNumber)
```

Then I want to extract the from field from a transaction but it doesn't exist.

```
    tx := block.Transactions()[0]
    tx.To().Hash() // => exists
    tx.From // => doesn't exist
```

Link to ethClient lib:
https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/a41ea8a97cd0f9db7a87e2dd15b380d4f1fbc311/ethclient/ethclient.go

Link to transaction object:
https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/a41ea8a97cd0f9db7a87e2dd15b380d4f1fbc311/core/types/transaction.go#L51

Does anybody know a work around?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "from" property of transactions is derived from the hash and signature, rather than being a field on the transaction itself. You can derive it with:

```
import "github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/core/types"

// ...

var signer types.Signer
switch {
case tx.Type() == types.AccessListTxType:
  signer = types.NewEIP2930Signer(tx.ChainId())
case tx.Type() == types.DynamicFeeTxType:
  signer = types.NewLondonSigner(tx.ChainId())
default:
  signer = types.NewEIP155Signer(tx.ChainId())
}
sender, _ := types.Sender(signer, tx)
```

Comment: Is it save to use always use `types.LatestSignerForChainID(netID)` instead as a signer?

Comment: It kind of depends on your use case. If you're trying to validate blocks, you need to make sure that the transactions included in that block were valid for that block, and that there aren't any transactions of a type that wasn't accepted at that point. If you're just trying to derive the sender of a transaction and don't care about whether the transaction is valid for a given block, `LatestSignerForChainID` should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the ethClient package to get the sender's address.

```go
var client *ethclient.Client

// Initialize the client
client, _ = ethclient.Dial("rpc URL")


sender, err := client.TransactionSender(context.Background(), tx, receipt.BlockHash, receipt.TransactionIndex)
```